Excel VBA Code - Inserting selected value from list
I'm having issues trying to get the selected worksheet to be inputted in the line of code
Set ws=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetArray())
I'm new to coding especially in excel VBA and tried to merge two codes together.
I used the loop to have a list of the worksheets to be able to print from.
I need to be able to select from the same list and send an email of the selected information
I keep getting type mismatch, but don't know how to fix it.
Please Help :)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim table As Range
Dim pic As Picture
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wordDoc


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'insert report, convert to image, and cut

Dim i As Long, c As Long
   Dim SheetArray() As String
    
   With ActiveSheet.ListBoxSH
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(i) Then
    ReDim Preserve SheetArray(c)
    SheetArray(c) = .List(i)
    c = c + 1
   End If
  Next i
End With
On Error GoTo 0
'Sheets (SheetArray().Insert)
    
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetArray())
Set table = ws.Range("A1:O37")
ws.Activate
table.Copy
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Paste
pic.Width = 1000
pic.Height = 1000
pic.Cut


If you Dim ws As Worksheet then you can only assign as single sheet to that variable.  Try Dim ws as Sheets   But you will need to loop over the selected sheets and copy each range in turn, so the whole array approach isn't really needed here.

If SheetArray is an array of strings, you'd need to do something like `For each SheetName in SheetArray: set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
